# Best practices for question answering — include by value or by reference?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Question triggered by comment thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741051/couple-noob-c-questions).

What is considered "best practice" for use of external resources in answering questions? This includes offline resources — books — as well as previous SO answers and other site info (often MSDN, since I am a Windows guy).

The comment thread referenced demonstrates that people have strong opinions either way and this is something that has nagged at me as I've gotten more active on the site. My opinion is that both approaches are valid, especially if the answer list for a question includes both direct (inline) assistance and also references to allow curious OPs to follow up and learn more.  Basically, let the questioner decide what approach works best for them.  It's not my job to decide whether a question is lazy or not — the question will get closed anyway if community makes that judgment.  I'm also biased against *just* telling people to read a book since I prefer to see people try to learn hands on, however dumb their initial attempts might look.

My preference is to include relevant information to help resolve the question by URL, rather than cut-and-paste or regenerate required code or information.  Trying to teach OP to fish rather than gutting and panfrying fish for them, I suppose.  Esp. since sample code is often present at referenced location.  Isn't that what the web and OOD/OOP are about — reducing redundancy in the name of simplicity?

For newbie and homework questions I think there is a balance between directing them towards standard texts, and helping more directly by targeted advice on the question topic.  I am curious to learn how other people articulate their approach.

Comment: Blindly adding indirection in the name of reducing redundancy does not necessarily create the simplest solution.

Comment: "include by value or by reference?" I thought you were asking about passing parameters in programming... :)

Comment: I think devinb says it all in his (accepted) [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) -cited as possible duplicate by @Arjan.

Comment: You're forgetting link rot.